# Compare the contents of a single column and sync rows in that colum

Tags: sql-server, data-synchronization

This is SQL Server - I have 3 rows of data in a single table based on location I want the data for a single field to match in all three locations e.g I have parts in three locations, location 1, 2, and 3 but the price for the part is different in each of the three locations, I would like to sync the price for all three locations

This is table 1 - fields include item number, location, price. e.g

```
item    loc.    price
123     1       0.1
123     2       0.2
123     3       0.3
```

My desired outcome is that location 2 and 3 will have the same price as location 1.

Comment: `UPDATE myTable SET price = 123.45`? I suspect we need more details on the actual tables involved, and how they're related.

Comment: If you need a single price for all locations, store it once, in a different table.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

Set up demo table with data

```
declare @T table (ItemNumber int, location int, price decimal(11,2))

insert into @T (ItemNumber,location, price) values
(1,1,10.00),(1,2,20.00),(1,3,30.00)

select * from @T
```

---

```
| ItemNumber | location | price |
|------------|----------|-------|
| 1          | 1        | 10.00 |
| 1          | 2        | 20.00 |
| 1          | 3        | 30.00 |
```

---

The update statement

```
UPDATE @T
SET price = (
        SELECT price
        FROM @T
        WHERE location = 1
        )
WHERE location <> 1

select * from @T
```

---

```
| ItemNumber | location | price |
|------------|----------|-------|
| 1          | 1        | 10.00 |
| 1          | 2        | 10.00 |
| 1          | 3        | 10.00 |
```

Comment: This works perfectly - thank you so much!!

Comment: @Melissa - if you think I have sufficiently answered your question, consider [accepting it](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).